# Apache LocationMatch not working

Tags: regex, apache, locationmatch

I have a the following directive inside of a `<VitrualHost/>` directive:

```
<LocationMatch "api/.*">
.....
</LocationMatch>
```

I am trying to hit my server with the following URL:

```
http://localhost/blah/api/blah?....
```

The stuff inside of my `<LocationMatch>` directive isn't being match. Maybe I don't understand how `<LocationMatch>` actually works. I would expect this to look at the URL and compare it with what is inside of the `""` of `<LocationMatch>`.

Edit:

The strange thing is this matches when I end the URL with ../api/

Comment: Perhaps, you should use `<LocationMatch ^/api/.*>`?

Comment: sadly that didn't work... thanks though.

Comment: `LocationMatch` occurs after `<Directory>` sections, .htaccess files and `<Files>` sections, so if you are rewriting the URL then this might not match. The regex `api/.*` is the same as `api/`.

Comment: I've commented out ALL the other <Directory> and <Files> sections.

Comment: How do you test it ? I mean what kind of directives do you have inside the `LocationMatch` container ?

Comment: Basically, I'm just setting a header right now... ultimately I'm going to do some mod_redirect stuff, as well.

Comment: Does the requested file at `localhost/blah/api/blah` exist? Because headers are set only if a file is returned (an existing file or an existing ErrorDocument). What do you mean with mod_redirect ? If you mean mod_rewrite, it will not work in `Location` or in `Files` containers.

Comment: As the others said -- the expression matches.  My guess would be you're rewriting with the [PT] flag, or something similar, and this URL is internally not used for the life of the request.

Comment: Thanks @Zimmi that was the answer I was looking for.